# Extract JSON from multiple URLs in Android Volley

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

I am currently using Volley to extract JSON contents using the following code.

```
JsonArrayRequest servicesStatus = new JsonArrayRequest(url1,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            // Having obj to process further
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            hidePDialog();

        }
    });
```

Now, I want one more JSON handler for the new URL and the dialog to be closed once it has successfully downloaded from both the URLs.

I tried to copy paste the above thing with url1 replaced by url2 and different jsonarrayrequest name. And added the hideDialog() in the second one. But the second one is not being called at all.

Comment: You will have to create new request and add it to the VolleyRequest que

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want make multiple request then you will have to add your **Request to Queue**. You can do it like this:

```
   RequestQueue request =  Volley.newRequestQueue(Context);
   request.add(FirstRequest);
   request.add(SecondRequest);
```

This should help you to add multiple request in Volley.